# Performance across to 2 tables, getting latest record from 2nd table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am using Code First, Entities, MVC3 + Razor, we have forms which have many steps in them (which also have to be audited)

I have `Forms`, which have `Steps`, so the model looks like this.

```
public class MyForm
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueReferenceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DetailsOfContact { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuditItem> AuditItems { get; set; }
}

public class AuditItem
{
    public int AuditItemId { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string ActionByUserUid { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAction { get; set; }
    public int Step { get; set; }

    public virtual MyForm MyForm { get; set; }
}
```

The trouble then comes when I want to display a user interface showing summary information from the form along with what the latest step it is at, details the progress of the many forms submitted, a table with which step they are at and a summary.  The performance is bad even with just a handful of records, let alone when we have thousands in it.  I have to query across the tables, with:

I have to get the step from the latest date, rather than just the latest 'step' number, as it's possible for a form to go back to a previous step.

```
int latestAuditStep = myForm.AuditItems
    .OrderByDescending(ai => ai.DateOfAction)
    .Select(ai => ai.Step)
     .First();
```

Obviously this is quite expensive, and I'm looking for a better way to tackle this modelling issue.

Note: I would have ideally liked to look at using WWF, as that seems the best tool to use in conjunction, but I have not had enough time up front to learn that, rather than just having to 'get the job done', so don't know whether it would have helped or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not perfect, but

```
return AuditItems.OrderBy(ai => ai.DateOfAction).Last()
```

certainly shortened the code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a database view.

And create a database-index on the FormID and DateOfAction column.